# Different Derailleurs with different shifters

Tags: shimano, gears, derailleur, shifter

I want to install hydraulic disk brakes on my bicycle, however I also need shifters as shifters and brakes are integrated on my bike.

I have 3 speed tourney FD TY 500 triple in front and Altus MD310 rear derailleur in the back.   Now I have trouble finding rear shifter, so can I use SL M310 Shifter with an RD 310 Derailleur?

Comment: I assume you mean hydraulic *disc* brakes specifically, as hydraulic rim brakes are extremely uncommon. Is your frame built to accommodate disc brakes?

Comment: How many gears in the back do you have?

Comment: Just for completeness, your bike already has disk brakes?   Checking that the frame has mounts for disk calipers, and the hubs have rotors.

Comment: It Came With Tektro Mechanical Diskbrakes

Answer (score 1):

Shimano 8 speed derailleurs and Shimano 8 speed shifters are always compatible.  So yes, you can use the 8 speed M310 shifter with your 8 speed derailleur.

Comment: Is this the same with front derailleurs?

Comment: No, not all Shimano 3x shifters are compatible with all 3x front derailleurs.  However as far as I know they are compatible within the larger categorisation of MTB vs Road.  So I suspect the Altus MTB shifter will work with the Tourney MTB front derailleur.  (There is a lot less information available online related to cable pull for front derailleurs compared to information on rear derailleurs)